# create a responsive ui like telegram using Qt Quick and qml?

Tags: qt, qml, responsive, fluid

I want to create a qml UI like the telegram that has responsive design.
in telegram when you have enough space chat area show in right and if not enough space chat area and other detail show as stack view.

I have on listview and a form to add a contact to the database.
I want if the window is large enough listview show in right of the form

or if not available space listview and the form is shown as stack view

just like telegram app

how to do this?

here is my qml file :

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 480

    ColumnLayout {
        id: rowLayout
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.margins: 5
        spacing: 10

        Text { text: qsTr("FirstName") }
        TextField { id: firstnameField }
        Text { text: qsTr("LastName") }
        TextField { id: lastnameField }
        Text { text: qsTr("Mobile") }
        TextField { id: mobileField }

        Button {
            text: qsTr("Add Data")
            onClicked: {
                database.insertIntoTable(firstnameField.text, lastnameField.text, mobileField.text)
                myModel.updateModel()
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Remove"
            onClicked: contextMenu.open();
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: tableView
        anchors.top: rowLayout.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.margins: 5
        anchors.topMargin: 30
        model: myModel

        Row {
            id: rl
            x:0
            y: -30
            Text { text: "FirstName"; font.bold: true; width: 120; }
            Text { text: "LastName"; font.bold: true; width: 120; }
            Text { text: "Mobile"; font.bold: true; width: 120; }
            spacing: 10
        }

        delegate: RowLayout {
            id: rowlayout
            spacing: 10

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: {
                    tableView.currentIndex = index
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: rc;
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: mouseArea.containsMouse ? "#55CCccCC" : "#00ffFFff"
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: rowLayoutBackground
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: (tableView.currentIndex == index) ? "#55CCccCC" : "#00ffFFff"
            }

            Column { Text { text: firstname; width: 120; } }
            Column { Text { text: lastname; width: 120; } }
            Column { Text { text: mobile; width: 120; } }
        }
    }

    Menu {
        id: contextMenu
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Remove")
            onTriggered: {
                dialogDelete.open()
            }
        }
    }

    MessageDialog {
        id: dialogDelete
        title: qsTr("Remove record")
        text: qsTr("Confirm the deletation of log entries")
        icon: StandardIcon.Warning
        standardButtons: StandardButton.Ok | StandardButton.Cancel

        onAccepted: {
            database.removeRecord(myModel.getId(tableView.currentIndex))
            myModel.updateModel()
        }
    }

}
```

[image: I want the result of my qml like this picture]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the demo to show responsive layout via QML [State](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html).

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    readonly property int responsiveWidth: 500
    width: 300; height: 500

    SwipeView  {
        id: swipeView
        currentIndex: 1
        anchors.fill: parent
        states: [
            State {
                when: window.width >= responsiveWidth
                ParentChange { target: contacts; parent: contactsContainer; }
                ParentChange { target: chat; parent: chatContainer; }
                PropertyChanges { target: indicator; visible: hide }
            }
        ]
        Item {
            Rectangle {
                id: contacts
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "lightblue"; border.width: 5; border.color: "white"
            }
        }
        Item {
            Rectangle{
                id: chat
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "lightgray"; border.width: 5; border.color: "white"
            }
        }
    }

    PageIndicator {
        id: indicator
        count: swipeView.count
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
        anchors.bottom: swipeView.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: swipeView.horizontalCenter
    }

    Row {
        id: splitView
        anchors.fill: parent
        Item {
            id: contactsContainer
            width: parent.width / 2; height: parent.height
        }
        Item {
            id: chatContainer
            width: parent.width / 2; height: parent.height
        }
    }
}
```

It is better to provide a runnable sample code for the problem explanation, so I simplified yours to shows the result of the responsive layout.

Complete source on [Github](https://github.com/arkceajin/QtDemos/tree/master/ResponsiveLayout)

**Update:**

The below code was updated to [SwipeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html) version. but the idea of doing responsive layout is always using STM to control it. I am not familiar with `SwipeView` so if you find any problem with the code please add a comment.

Comment: this is sample code i want to be fluid like telegram : https://github.com/aliakbarRashidi/qml-contact-book-sqlite

Comment: Dear Jiu Thnaks. Please if you can edit my github project to be responsive like you posted in git in addition that when small screen rectangle chat be stack child with a back button to show rectangle contacts

Comment: yes, please, i am beginner.   or please change your code that when window is small then two rectangle be in a stack manner way with a button on rectangle contacts that show rectangle chat and a a back button on rectangle chat to return to rectangle contacts

Comment: may i have your email, please?  arrivalhacker@gmail.com

Comment: @AliakbarRashidi I add the buttons(hide & show), updated the source on Github.

Comment: @AliakbarRashidi If you have any problem, `StackOverflow` is the right place to ask and share the solution & knowledge.

Comment: Dear Jiu, thanks, it's nice; but i want to when window is small then contacts and chat show in a stack view manner. how to do this?

Comment: I haven't used the telegram. What you mean you want `window is small then...`? Is that if window width greater than height shows the two rectangles in the horizontal layout(desktop) otherwise vertical layout(phone device)?

Comment: i want behavior like fragment in android for the qml.

Comment: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b768afff0888fcb8cbe1704b0609b53110276969/687474703a2f2f646576656c6f7065722e616e64726f69642e636f6d2f696d616765732f66756e64616d656e74616c732f667261676d656e74732e706e67

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/split_view/use_split_view_to_show_two_controllers/Images/Picture_1.png

Comment: @AliakbarRashidi I updated the answer&github, please take a look.

Comment: very very thanks. how can i contact you?(telegram, email, wechat, mobile or anyway)

Comment: @AliakbarRashidi For what purpose you need? Any problem with the code simply put it on here.

Comment: another reason I don't want to say here.

Comment: @AliakbarRashidi Sorry, if it's not related to programming. BTW people in StackOverflow using spiritual power to communicate instead of telegram email... :D